# Why don't my industry conversion techs work?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

Every system has two conversion techs: industry to science and industry to dust. Most of the times, choosing one of these options immediately updates the system's science / dust production.

However, occasionally, choosing one of these options does not change the system's production. Why does it happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug; restarting the game sorted it out.